# I try to show a dialog with an action from a menuitem but doesn't work

Tags: primefaces, dialog

I try to show a dialog with an action from a menuitem but doesn't work

I have the follow menuitem:

`<p:menuitem value="About" action="#{loginManagedBean.showAbout}" icon="icon-info-circled"/>`

and in my managed bean I have:

```
public void showAbout(){
    RequestContext.getCurrentInstance().execute("PF('dgAbout').show()");
}
```

but doesnt work

I use PrimeFaces 5

the dialog to show is:

```
<h:panelGrid>
                <p:dialog widgetVar="dgAbout" header="About us" 
                          hideEffect="fade"
                          showEffect="fade"
                          resizable="true"
                          modal="true">
                    <h:panelGrid>
                        <h:outputText value="INFO"/>
                    </h:panelGrid>
                </p:dialog>
 </h:panelGrid>
```

Comment: Hi, welcome to Stackoverflow... What is the actual problem? 'Does not work' is not a lot to investigate. What did you debug, inspect etc... any errors anywhere?

Comment: I debug it and the thread enter to the bean but doesnt show the page and no errors in the console

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The code was right, the problem was a navigation rule established by a 
colleague without inform to me. 
Thanks for help

Sorry for the disadvantages